# localStorage remove one value and keep existing values

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

I am trying to store two type of lists (add, remove) into `localStorage`. By default, I will add some values. And then user can remove that name if they don't want it. Once they remove the name from `#notneeded` list it will add into `#needed` list. I have done that case too.

**[JsBin Link](https://jsbin.com/tuliyineca/edit?html,js,output)**

**Default Case:**

[image]

**Problem is Here:**

Now, you can see. I clicked `EEE` from second list. In visual screen it works fine. `EEE` removed from second list and added into first list. In `localStorage` first list is working fine as expected.

> add => ["AAA","BBB","EEE"]

But, In second list I am expecting it should update like this

> remove => ["CCC","DDD","FFF","GGG"]

instead of this

> ["CCC","DDD","EEE","FFF","GGG","\n\t\t
>
> CCC
>
> DDD
>
> FFF
>
> GGG
>
> "]

What I am doing wrong here?

[image]

**Javascript**

```
          const selected = document.getElementById('needed');
          const unselect = document.getElementById('notneeded');

            //selected lists onload event
            window.addEventListener('load', function(e){
                var getLists = localStorage.getItem("add");
                if (getLists === null) {
                    const defaultLists = [ 'AAA', 'BBB' ];
                    const unselectedLists = [ 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE', 'FFF', 'GGG' ];

                    defaultLists.forEach(item => {
                      liMaker(0, item);
                    });

                    unselectedLists.forEach(item => {
                      liMaker(1, item);
                    });

                    localStorage.setItem('add', JSON.stringify(defaultLists));
                    localStorage.setItem('remove', JSON.stringify(unselectedLists));
                } else {
                    const defaultLists = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('add'));
                    const unselectedLists = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('remove'));

                    defaultLists.forEach(item => {
                      liMaker(0, item);
                    });

                    unselectedLists.forEach(item => {
                      liMaker(1, item);
                    });
                }
            });

            //unselected lists onclick event
            unselect.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                const tgt = e.target;

                let liArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('add')) || [];
                liMaker(0, tgt.innerHTML);
                liArray.push(tgt.innerHTML);

                localStorage.setItem('add', JSON.stringify(liArray));

                if(tgt.tagName.toUpperCase() == "LI") {
                    e.target.parentNode.removeChild(tgt);
                }

                const unselect = document.getElementById('notneeded').innerHTML;
                let uliArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('remove')) || [];
                uliArray.push(unselect);

                console.log(uliArray);

                localStorage.setItem('remove', JSON.stringify(uliArray));
            });

            const liMaker = (num, text) => {
              const li = document.createElement('li');
              li.textContent = text;
              if(num === 0) {
                selected.appendChild(li);
              } else if(num === 1) {
                unselect.appendChild(li);
              }  
            }
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="needed">
</ul>
<ul id="notneeded">
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you please add a console.log to print the tgt.innerHTML in the unselect onclick  handler? I'm quite certain its due to the handler being defined on the ul the tgt is the ul itself

Comment: You need to add onclick handler to `li` elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is here

```
const unselect = document.getElementById('notneeded').innerHTML;
```

This returns string, not actual values you expect

```js
const unselect = document.getElementById('notneeded')
const badValues = unselect.innerHTML
const goodValues = [].map.call(unselect.children, (e) => e.textContent) // using .call
const goodValues2 = [...unselect.children].map(e => e.textContent) // using spread operator

console.log(badValues)
console.log(goodValues)
console.log(goodValues2)
```

```html
<ul id='notneeded'>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the innerHtml of the ul to the `uliArray`

```
  const unselect = document.getElementById('notneeded').innerHTML;
  let uliArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('remove')) || [];
  uliArray.push(unselect);
```